# Reading File on Google Drive using Dart

Tags: dart, google-drive-api

I created a configuration file (Simple Text File) on my Google Drive and now I would like to read it from my Chrome Packaged Dart Application. But I'm not able to get more information of the file than it's name, size etc.

For accessing Google Drive I use the *google_drive_v2_api*.

Any suggestion on how to get the contents of my configuration file would be great! Thanks!

Comment: From personal experience with the auto-generated client google_*_v*_api packages I'd avoid them like the plague. They're auto-generated from the JSON discovery files and a pain to use. I've had far more success writing my own libraries to access google services (shameless plug for google_cloud_datastore library).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did some test in my own chrome app, uploading and downloading a simple file:

```dart
 chrome.identity.getAuthToken(new chrome.TokenDetails(interactive: true ))
.then((token){
   OAuth2 auth = new SimpleOAuth2(token);
   var drive = new gdrive.Drive(auth)..makeAuthRequests=true;
   drive.files.insert({},content:window.btoa('hello drive!')).then((sentMeta){

      print("File sent! Now retrieving...");

      drive.files.get(sentMeta.id).then((repliedMeta){
      HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest()..open('GET', repliedMeta.downloadUrl)
        ..onLoad.listen((r)=>print('here is the result:'+r.target.responseText));
      auth.authenticate(request).then((oAuthReq)=>oAuthReq.send());
    });
  });
});
```

It works, but the HttpRequest to get content back seems heavy...

But i really recommend you to a take look to **chrome.storage.sync** if your config file size is < to 4ko... If not, you could also use the chrome **SyncFileSystem API**... They are both easier to use, and SyncFileSystem use Drive as backend.

Answer (score -2):

This page on [downloading files](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads) talks through the process for getting the contents of a file.